# What's a good convex optimization library?

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, convex

I am looking for a C++ library, and I am dealing with convex objective and constraint functions.

Comment: Most LP solvers have their own way of defining problem sets. Programmatic interfaces for it is mostly sugar coating.

Comment: I am using cvxopt, and to install I just downloaded the precompiled libraries from  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxopt, then did pip install (downloaded wheel), then made sure to import numpy before using it.

Comment: @Phylliida: Does CVXOPT have a C++ version/interface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am guessing your problem is non-linear. Where i work, we use [SNOPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOPT), [Ipopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) and another proprietary solver (not for sale). We have also tried and heard good things about [Knitro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KNITRO).

As long as your problem is convex, all these solvers work well.

They all have their own API, but they all ask for the same information : values, first and second derivatives.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your problems are nonlinear, you can use free and open-sourced [OPT++](http://acts.nersc.gov/opt++/), available from Sandia Lab. I have used it in one project in C++ and it was easy to use and worked well.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, the CPLEX solver is the best convex optimization solver. Its the state of the art in LP solvers. Does convex optimization really well. While looking for it, I see that its IBM's software now. You can find it here : http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex/

Comment: You can find other open source solvers and their performance benchmarks here: http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpfree.html Also, dont forget to check out http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation

Comment: Linear implies convex, not the other way around.

Comment: cplex solves linearly or quadratically constrained convex problems.  It's very fast, but it doesn't handle general convex problems.